Notificaciones Push No Funcionan
Tengo dos App una que manda notificaciones push y otra que las recibe, las dos app en el mismo proyecto. Hasta hace poco funcionaban bien pero ahora ha dejado de funcionar a causa de que se mandaban por API de Could Messaging (heredada) y ahora ahi que mandarla por API de Firebase Cluod Messaging (V1).
Os pongo como lo envio y como lo recibo en cada app que como he dicho me funcionaba bien hasta hace poco:
App que envia las notificaciones Push
Clase: MandarNotificacion
Primero la llamo
                                String detalle = "Cambios en los Planos del IES Emerita Augusta.";
                            MandarNotificacion mandarNotificacion = new MandarNotificacion();
                            mandarNotificacion.NotificacionEnviar( detalle, getActivity() );

Y aqui la ejecuto
package com.delgadovalhondo.iesadministrador;

import android.content.Context;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MandarNotificacion {
public void NotificacionEnviar(String detalle, Context context) {

    RequestQueue myrequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {

        json.put( "to", "/topics/enviaratodos");
        JSONObject notificacion = new JSONObject();
        notificacion.put( "titulo", "IES Emérita Augusta");
        notificacion.put( "detalle", detalle);
        json.put( "data", notificacion );
        String URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new  JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST,URL,json,null, null ) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Content-type", "application/json");
                header.put("authorization", "key=AAAARd3VFXM.......");
                return header;
            }
        };
        myrequest.add(request);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
En la App que las recibe:
    package com.delgadovalhondo.emeritaaugusta;
    
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationChannel;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
    import java.util.Random;

public class RecibirNotificaciones extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    super.onNewToken( token );
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("enviaratodos").addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    });
    /*FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("enviaratodos").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived( remoteMessage );

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0 ) {
        String titulo  = remoteMessage.getData().get("titulo");
        String detalle  = remoteMessage.getData().get("detalle");
        mayorqueoreo (titulo, detalle);
    }

}

private void mayorqueoreo(String titulo, String detalle) {
    String id = "mensaje";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this, id );
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel( id, "iesemeritaaugusta", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH  );
        notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel( notificationChannel );
    }
    builder.setAutoCancel( true )
           .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
           .setContentTitle( titulo )
           .setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher )
           .setContentText( detalle )
           .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
           .setContentIntent( clicknoti() )
           .setContentInfo( "iesemeritaaugusta" );

    Random random = new Random( );
    int idNotify = random.nextInt(8000);
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify( idNotify, builder.build() );
}

public PendingIntent clicknoti() {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra( "color", "rojo" );
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
}

}
y en el manifest
<service
        android:name=".RecibirNotificaciones"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>

¿Como lo puedo cambiar para que funcione?
Gracias

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

"Tengo dos App una que manda notificaciones push y otra que las
recibe, las dos app en el mismo proyecto."

En mi caso también podía enviar notificaciones desde la misma aplicación, pero ahora ya no se puede realizar esto, ya que para realizar el envío de notificaciones ha sufrido cambios con la API HTTP V1.
Por ejemplo:
La url usada es:
  String URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

pero ahora para realizar el envio se deben realizar los siguientes cambios:

Cuenta con la versión /v1 en la ruta.
La ruta contiene el ID del proyecto de Firebase de la app en el formato /projects/myproject-ID/. Puedes encontrar este ID en la pestaña Configuración general del proyecto de Firebase console.
Especifica de manera explícita el método send como :send.

por lo tanto la url tendría que ser de esta forma, definiendo tu id de proyecto:
  String URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<Id Projecto>/messages:send"

Revisa la documentación:
Migra de HTTP heredado a HTTP v1

Ahora lo ideal es enviar notificaciones desde una app que tenga Credenciales predeterminadas de la aplicación (ADC) de Google o mediante una cuenta de servicio.

Autoriza solicitudes de envío HTTP v1
Según los detalles de tu entorno de servidor, usa una combinación de
las siguientes estrategias para autorizar las solicitudes de servidor
a los servicios de Firebase:
• Credenciales predeterminadas de la aplicación (ADC) de Google.
• Un archivo JSON de una cuenta de servicio
• Un token de acceso de OAuth 2.0 de corta duración de una cuenta de servicio
Si la aplicación se ejecuta en Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, App Engine o
Cloud Functions (incluido Cloud Functions para Firebase), usa el
servicio Credenciales predeterminadas de la aplicación (ADC). ADC usa
tu cuenta de servicio predeterminada existente para obtener
credenciales y autorizar solicitudes. Además, permite realizar pruebas
locales flexibles mediante la variable de entorno
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Si deseas lograr la automatización más
completa del flujo de autorización, usa ADC y las bibliotecas de
servidor del SDK de Admin.
Si la aplicación se ejecuta en un entorno de servidor que no es de
Google, deberás descargar un archivo JSON de una cuenta de servicio
desde el proyecto de Firebase. Puedes usar la variable de entorno
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS para autorizar solicitudes con las
credenciales que obtuviste de forma manual, siempre y cuando tengas
acceso a un sistema de archivos que contenga el archivo de claves
privadas. De lo contrario, debes hacer referencia al archivo de la
cuenta de servicio en el código. Este proceso se debe realizar con
mucho cuidado para evitar exponer tus credenciales.


He conseguido desde firebase mandar una notificacion tal y como lo tengo en RecibirNotificacion a todos los que tienen instalado esta app y con el canal de notificacion enviaratodos. Pero no soy capaz de enviar notificacion a esta app desde otra app dentro del mismo proyecto (EnviarNotificacion). Me podrias dar un ejemplo o un video qye mardar notificacion. Gracias.

Hola @Fernando veo que hay preguntas que se han respondido, pero no has realizado ninguna acción, recuerda que es importante marcarlas como solución si estas te ayudaron a solucionar el problema ., revisa [tour]

Formulo otra vez la pregunta:
Al mandar una notificacion:
  public void NotificacionEnviar(String detalle, Context context) {
    RequestQueue myrequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put( "to", "/topics/enviaratodos");
        JSONObject notificacion = new JSONObject();
        notificacion.put( "titulo", "Porra de la Cofradía Infantil");
        notificacion.put( "detalle", detalle);
        json.put( "data", notificacion );

        String URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/porracofradiainfantil/messages:send";


        JsonObjectRequest request = new  JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST,URL,json,null, null ) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Content-type", "application/json");
                header.put("authorization", "Bearer ya29.AAAA");
                return header;
            }
        };
        myrequest.add(request);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

al ejecutarla
String detalle = "Se acaba de abrir la Jornada";
                MandarNotificacion mandarNotificacion = new MandarNotificacion();
                mandarNotificacion.NotificacionEnviar( detalle, MainActivity.this );

Sale este error:

E/Volley: [2054] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 401 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/porracofradiainfantil/messages:send
D/TrafficStats: tagSocket(159) with statsTag=0x60f5743, statsUid=-1
E/Volley: [2054] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 401 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/porracofradiainfantil/messages:send
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
E/GoogleApiManager: Failed to get service from broker.
java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.

y no se ejecuta la notoficacion.
Ademas me gustaria saber de donde saca del proyecto la AAAA de esta linea, es decir, el codigo que hay que poner ahi.
header.put("authorization", "Bearer ya29.AAAA")


Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

Ya la he formulado otra vez
